# Lazy Class Aliases?

Tags: php, performance

The class_alias function seems to load the class into memory immediately when the statement executes instead of the first time the class is actually used. Is it possible / recommended to setup some kind of lazy loading mechanism for class aliases?

For instance, perhaps store the the aliases in an array, and in an __autoload function check that array and define the alias when the class is actually used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is to not use the function to alias classes, but use the `use` construct:

```
<?php
namespace foo\bar;
use \some\other\class\name as name;

$foo = new name();
```

That will be lazy loaded.

Comment: This would require us to write it on every single Class. `class_alias()` would be a global approach, however as the OP said it sadly loads the classes into memory immediately.